# How should jquery .after work in this situation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I don't know if I am using the .after incorrectly but it is my understanding that it *should* display the element after the one I specify? - the hello world selection box after the Option1 select?

```
<select id="cselect" >
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>

</select>

$('#cselect').chosen();

var test = '<select id="dselect" ><option>Hello World</option></select>';  

$('#cselect').after(test);

$('#dselect').chosen();
```

fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/4/

What am I missing? TIA

Comment: Your sample code and the jsFiddle have a missing `>` `...orld</option</selc...`

Comment: @phuzi fixed it thanks, doesn't seem to solve the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the chosen plugin. When you first call `chosen` on the first `select`, you end up with this (pseudo code):

```
<select id="select1"></select>
<div id="chosenForSelect1"></div>
```

After you append the new `select`, you have this:

```
<select id="select1"></select>
<select id="select2"></select>
<div id="chosenForSelect1"></div>
```

Then you call `.chosen()` on the second `select` and end up with this:

```
<select id="select1"></select>
<select id="select2"></select>
<div id="chosenForSelect2"></div>
<div id="chosenForSelect1"></div>
```

So the actual `select` element is added after the first, but the `div`s to support the chosen plugin are out of whack. It might be better to append the new `select` to the container, add a container for each `select`, or append after the html for the chosen plugin.

Comment: All of the answers will work but this one works the best for me because I am loading the second select based on the first select. Thanks for all the replies!!!

Answer (score 2):

`.after()` inserts content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements. You are using it in correct way. Check the DOM order that got created with above code. You can able to see the first HTML element inside `body` tag is:

```
<select id="cselect" style="display: none;">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

and second one is:

```
<select id="dselect" style="display: none;"><option>Hello World</option></select>
```

As chosen is created `div's` dynamically order is changed.

**Solution:** Once you added dynamic html code to DOM using .after apply chosen on select like:

```
var test = '<select id="dselect" ><option>Hello World</option</select>';  

$('#cselect').after(test);
 $('#cselect').chosen();
$('#dselect').chosen();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/5/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

if you take a look at the HTML generated by your plugin it actually hides the select and adds a div following it that is the actual select that is rendered.

So what you end up with is actually:

```
<select id="cselect" style="display: none;">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
</select>
<select id="dselect" style="display: none;">
    <option>Hello World</option>
</select>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 94px;" title="" id="dselect_chosen"> ... </div>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 76px;" title="" id="cselect_chosen"> ... </div>
```

You actually end up inserting dselect before cselect.